# ios tableview displays cell as multiline only ios8 not ios7

Tags: uitableview, swift, multiline

I have a tableview that displays as multiple lines, as intended, when running the simulator under ios8. When running under ios7 it limits all the cells to 2 rows. The recommendation I found numerous places online was to use numberOfLines = 0 as seen below but this does nothing. Also tried sizeToFit and lineBreakMode and they have no effect. Any ideas? Creating custom cell seems like overkill but do I need to do that?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...
    //cell.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping
    //cell.textLabel?.sizeToFit()
    cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0;
    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(formattedPlateComments[indexPath.row])"

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `numberOfLines=0` on the Label instance is correct, since this specifies an unlimited number of lines. For iOS 7 compatibility, however, you need to also define `heightForRowAtIndexPath`, i.e.:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> CGFloat {
    return 20    // you can also programmatically calculate a desired height
}
```

Using `numberOfLines=0` and `heightForRowAtIndexPath`, I was able to display multiple lines in my tableView in both iOS 8 & 7.